# How to connect to Twitter from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need share on twitter in my application through iPhone.App has to tweet in the twitter. There is a button action on clicking which twitter login page should open.
How to do this?
Code for this appreciable..
Thank You.

Comment: 0% accept means you're vastly less likely to get answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone). However, if you are using SDK < 3.2 then you need to download an old version. There is a demo app included which shows how to login and tweet clearly.

For a tutorial on this, check [this](http://blancer.com/tutorials/93839/iphone-sdk-connect-to-twitter-with-oauth/).

Comment: How to use Twitter-OAuth-iPhone in iPhone application?

Comment: Check the demo app. It's pretty simple. Check the edit. I have added a tutorial link.

Comment: Download the project from github. Already provided you the link. Click the download button on the right side of the page. Demo project is included there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to refer to Twitter's page for libraries [using OAuth on iOS](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/oauth_libraries#objectivec).

Alternatively you may always use the "?status=" method:

```
http://mobile.twitter.com/?status=<YOUR MSG IN URI-ENCODED FORM>
```

However that may not work if the user have not signed in yet. Try the OAuth methods which would be harder to implement but safer for sending messages.