# How to integrate twitter app in my iphone?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, twitter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to connect to Twitter from iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012349/how-to-connect-to-twitter-from-iphone)

hi,
 can anybody please explain how to integrate the twitter app in my iphone app with simple example?

Comment: Probably people can, but you could have found lots of questions and answers on this topic yourself easily.

Answer (score 2):

You have twitter iOS SDK, which can be downloaded from [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios). And the documentation there is good enough to get you started.

From iOS 6 onwards, you can use Apple's own [SocialFramework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233) to post tweets. From Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6.html)

> The Social framework (Social.framework) provides a simple interface
>   for accessing the user’s social media accounts. This framework
>   supplants the Twitter framework that was introduced in iOS 5 and adds
>   support for other social accounts, including Facebook and Sina’s Weibo
>   service. Apps can use this framework to post status updates and images
>   to a user’s account. This framework works with the Accounts framework
>   to provide a single sign-on model for the user and to ensure that
>   access to the user’s account is approved.

Comment: hi, iam using twitteragent in my app but when posting the tweets to my account but its not displayed in my twitter blog.